# Flask - Babel - crumbled diacritics

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

I need to create translations for a Flask application using Babel or Babelex.

Run:

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o messages.pot .
```

...succeeds, creating `messages.pot`.

In the file `messages.pot` there are changes:

```
#: service/menu/Menu.py:53
msgid "A new menu has been successfully saved!"
msgstr "Nové menu bylo úspěšně uloženo!"
```

Then I create a `.po` file.

```
pybabel init -i messages.pot -d translations -l cs
```

The `*.po` file content is:

```
#: service/menu/Menu.py:53
msgid "A new menu has been successfully saved!"
msgstr "NovĂ© menu bylo ĂşspÄ›ĹˇnÄ› uloĹľeno!"
```

The translated files are broken, all files are in UTF-8. When I compile `*.po` file as `*.mo` file, it's the same.

Comment: I know it’s an old one, but please note that you shouldn’t add translations in your `.pot` file, but in the `.po` files generated with `pybabel update`. Also, did you find a solution to your problem? I’m facing a similar one, although not the same.